# How to move E..H commits into a separate repository?

Tags: git, dvcs

Say, I have `Repo1` as follows

```
special ->                      E ... F ... G ... H
                               /
master  ->  A ... B ... C ... D ... X ... Y ... Z
```

how do I start a `Repo2` with `master` from `E`? That is for `Repo2` I'm not concerned with history before `E` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the history that you want to preserve contains merges, the simplest way may be to use a graft to  temporarily cut off the unwanted history, then filter-branch to create a branch that has that view of history as the permanent one.

```
cd /path/to/repo
git checkout -b newbranch special
git rev-parse E > .git/info/grafts
git filter-branch
rm .git/info/grafts
```

This assumes that you don't currently have any grafts. Since grafts are rarely used and it would probably be a good idea to do this in a fresh clone anyway, that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout --orphan newbranch E
git commit -c E
git cherry-pick F..H
git init --bare /path/to/new/repo
git push /path/to/new/repo HEAD:master
```

Comment: cherry-pick is faster than using patches. I like it. +1

Comment: @qqx I moved from a similar approach (with --strategy=recursive --strategy-option=theirs for auto conflict resolution) due to numerous "Commit [...] is a merge but no -m option was given." which are hard to handle for thousands of commits. Any ideas how to handle them in batch?

Answer (score 0):

The easy and obvious way: Check out E and make a copy of the working directory, but make sure you don't carry along the .git directory. Now initialize a new git repo from there and move the other commits over. `git format-patch` and `git apply` are your friends.

Comment: Applying a bunch of patches seemed to me by some reason a hard way. The same as cherry-picking. I hoped for something more pretty %)

Comment: @idlesign: You could always generate patches with `git format-patch` and apply with some variation of `git am *.patch` -- not so hard.

Answer (score 0):

While [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) could be involved, [this article](http://blog.briang.org/?p=217) gives an original solution with patches:

> Create a bunch of patches, like so:

```
git checkout find-ls
git format-patch 9758db3 # where find-ls branched
```

> If you need to have your new repo have a different structure, you might need to hack the patches. I just used:

```
perl -pi -E 's|LEADING-DIR/||g' *.patch
```

> Then you can apply the patches:

```
mv 0*.patch where/I/want/my/new/repo
cd where/I/want/my/new/repo
git am *.patch
```

Comment: I don't see how `filter-branch` may be involved w/o further directories joggling, any example?

Comment: @idlesign I was looking for `filter-branch` examples (as in https://github.com/github/teach.github.com/blob/gh-pages/technology/_posts/2001-01-01-lesson-filter-branch.md), but patches are the simplest solution here.